# Where is this SQL Debug output coming from?

Tags: ruby, debugging

My output when running my ruby cli file includes lines like:

`D, [2018-11-17T15:33:29.481676 #45237] DEBUG -- :   Patient Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"`

I copied things from other sample projects for my environment, Gemfile, and Rakefile, and obviously something is set up to output this. How do I turn it off?

My gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-rescue' 
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
gem 'pry-nav'
gem 'activesupport'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "sinatra"
gem "sqlite3"
gem "rake"
gem "database_cleaner"

group :test do
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec'
end
```

My rakefile:

```
# ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"
$LOADED_FEATURES << 'fake/active_support/core_ext/hash'

require_relative './config/environment'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'

task :console do
  Pry.start
end
```

My environment:

```
ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"
$LOADED_FEATURES << 'fake/active_support/core_ext/hash'

require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: "sqlite3",
  database: "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.sqlite"
)

require 'active_record'
require 'rake'

Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/models", "*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../lib", "*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active record logs sql output in development mode by default.  To disable it,
try adding this line before the section after it like so

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: "sqlite3",
  database: "db/#{ENV['SINATRA_ENV']}.sqlite"
)
```